# activemq embedded broker

Tags: activemq-classic

In ActiveMQ, there is a concept called BrokerService. Normally for learning purposes, I am starting the broker from the command line using 'activemq' which starts the Broker.
What is the difference between starting the broker this way and using the BrokerService.start();

My guess is that when you use 'activemq' , the broker starts in its own jvm, when you use BrokerService.start(), the broker is using the existing JVM.
Is this correct?

Also, if someone can point to a resource that explains how the broker architecture is implemented in a traditional j2ee server like weblogic, that would be much appreciated.

I am mostly seeking clarification of how a broker can be deployed on a cluster?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the ActiveMQ in action book. That is awesome and explains everything

[My blog](http://javaprogrammingtips4u.blogspot.com)

Comment: That's not a good answer. Please provide at least a minimum on information. You may provide links and external references, but an answer should be basically solving the question by itself.